# Angular update using ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force

Tags: angular, npm

I update my Angular project v8 to last update and I face problem. My `package.json` was as follows:

```
{
    "name": "website-admin-angular",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/animations": "angular/animations-builds",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/common": "~8.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "~8.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "~8.0.3",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "angular-bootstrap-md": "^8.1.0",
        "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
        "angular2-chartjs": "^0.5.1",
        "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
        "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
        "ng-http-loader": "^6.0.1",
        "ng2-charts": "2.3.0",
        "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
        "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
        "ngx-loading": "^3.0.1",
        "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
        "ngx-ui-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.6",
        "@angular/cli": "^8.3.21",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.3",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.4.3"
    }
}
```

after run

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
```

my `package.json` became as follows:

```
{
  "name": "website-admin-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-material-components/datetime-picker": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^8.1.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-http-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "2.3.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-loading": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.1.0",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.6"
  }
}
```

and when run

```
ng s -o
```

I get this error

[image]

and my log is

```
[error] Error: NGCC failed.
at NgccProcessor.process (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:69:19)
at E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:576:31
at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:55:30)
at createWebpack (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:21:36)
at Object.runWebpackDevServer (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:47:12)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:164:32)
at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:49:27)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
at E:\AdminPanelGit\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps at https://update.angular.io/ - it is advised to upgrade multiple major versions one at a time, i.e. 8->9->10, not 8->10.